# In XCode view editor is it possible to adust size of multiple selections

Tags: iphone, xcode, button, multipleselection, resource-editor

I've just started using XCode.  Created a calculator with over 20 buttons.  I was surprised to find that when multiple buttons are selected in the Xcode view editor, resizing one does not resize all.  Is it possible to resize multiple selections?  Going back to my days with MacDraw/ClarisDraw using a handle on one of multiply selected objects sized all objects proportionally.

Further is there a "Distribute evenly" horizontally or vertically to arrange multiple buttons evenly spaced?  This was also a MacDraw/ClarisDraw feature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You simply use the Size inspector (View->Utilites->Show Size Inspector or Cmd+Option+5) and you can adjust the width and height values for the items numerically.

[image]

If it says "Multiple Values" you can simply overwrite that.

Comment: Thank you, with your answer I was able to make it work.  I would still like to have a "distribute evenly" operation like in MacDraw/ClarisDraw though.